# How can I insert search box in front html page?

Tags: javascript, search

I tried to show the search box in a custom front page, which is a regular HTML page.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Going to need version of Drupal and to see how you are trying to add it (code).  Also are you trying to use a custom template file for your homepage, or your homepage isn't in Drupal at all?

Comment: I think you should read more on how Drupal work, Creating a new blank HTML page is not the right way to create a custom front page. take a look here for starters http://drupal.org/node/265172

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking, but if you want to output a block directly in code you can use [module_invoke()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7).

IE.

Drupal 7

```
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 'current_search');
```

Drupal 6

```
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', 'current_search');
```

Then render the contents of $block.